# How to calculate indegree and outdegree for a graph in directed graph SML code?

Tags: smlnj, ml

I have a tuple like `(1,2),(3,4),(4,5)`. Edges: `1->2`, `3->4` and so on.

How calculate in degree and out degree for each vertex?

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function take in a list of tuples which are the edges.

accumulate another list of tuples or (records), with format of [(node, inDgree, OutDgree),...]

records [{node=int, inDgree=int, outDgree = int},...]

```
fun degrees ((a,b)::(as,bs)) = ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but am not clear. I have List of tuples like [(1,2),(2,3),(3,4)]. I removed the tuple format and converted as list format like [1,2,2,3,3,4]. Now i need to calculate in degree and out degree for each vertex i.e; 1,2,3,4.

Comment: you actually do not need to convert the tuples to a list. In the function body you can process the tuples one by one. For a tuple (s,d), write a helper function to check whether it is already in your result list, if in, increment the outdegree by one, if not, create a new entry in your result list with the outdegree to be one.

Answer (score 0):

The out-degree of vertex `v` is the number of pairs `(x, y)` where `x == v`, since each such pair corresponds to an edge starting at `v`. Likewise, the in-degree of `v` is the number of pairs `(x, y)` where `y == v`.

Does that give you enough of the basic idea?